# In Google Sheets, how to query and sum all values which have the same description?

Tags: google-sheets, sum, unique

I am using a query formula to import data from a different sheet. 
However after querying the data, I got the same code which I need to sum the episode and the value with unique formula therefore after querying only show unique code. I'm not sure how to mix the formula.

My query formula is the following:

```
=QUERY(Paste!A:M,"SELECT A,B,C ORDER BY C DESC LIMIT 15")
```

My spreadsheet link is the following:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A6lGIlU147Y_0WFD7Btkq4IMuY-Z3D1HsNiTgjLjm0o/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

As above image. Under column A I have same code for FMEM1 due to my raw data separate it for some reason. I don't want the same code separated. I want unique code not separated and sum the episode and sum the value

Comment: *Link not public*

Comment: hi, its public now

Comment: Also, you might want to let people know what program / language etc. you're having the problem with, try some more/ other etc. 
That way more people will see your question and be able to help.

Comment: An example of how the data should look after query could also help w/ finding an answer.

Comment: Hello, what column do you mean by "description"? `Code` or `Episode`? If it's Code, are Episodes added too?

Comment: hi @Jescanellas, I have edited my post.

Answer (score 2):

try

`=query({A3:A17,B3:B17,C3:C17},"select Col1, Sum(Col2),Sum(Col3) group by Col1 label Col1 'Code',Sum(Col2) 'Total Episode',Sum(Col3) 'Total Value'")`

---

**Screenshot**

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hi @tedinoz Thank you,  can we make it order by total value and descending?

Comment: `=query({A3:A17,B3:B17,C3:C17},"select Col1, Sum(Col2),Sum(Col3) group by Col1 order by Sum(Col3) desc label Col1 'Code',Sum(Col2) 'Total Episode',Sum(Col3) 'Total Value'")` The syntax for Query is found [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#order-by).  Once you have seen it used once or twice, it all starts to make sense FWIW, one of THE most valuable things that I learned recently is that the various clauses MUST be a in [specific order](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#language-clauses).

Comment: Hi @tedinoz. Thank you very much for your guidance